# Objective c Regex Expression

Tags: objective-c, regex

I have some code for getting images out of html source...

```
NSError *error;

NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression         
                              regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(https?)\\S*(png|jpg|jpeg|gif)"
                              options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                              error:&error];

[regex enumerateMatchesInString:htmlstr 
                        options:0 
                          range:NSMakeRange(0, htmlstr.length) 
                     usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *result, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop) {
                         [imagesURLStringArray addObject:[htmlstr substringWithRange:result.range]];
                     }];
```

I am struggling to get the proper image if the link is like the following...

```
<a href='http://imagelink.jpg'><img src='http://imagesource.jpg'....
```

how can i just extract the source rather than the link?

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether objective-c regex supports lookbehind or not. You can try with this lookbehind:

```
regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(?<=src=['\"])(https?)\\S*(png|jpg|jpeg|gif)"
                               +------------+
```

Comment: `@"(?<=src=['\"])(https?)\\S*(png|jpg|jpeg|gif)"` works, NSRegularExpression does support lookbehind assertions. The only problem is if there's any spacing between `src`, `=`, and `'` or `"`, as you can't use unbounded operators in a look behind.

Comment: Optional space checking using `\s*` will do around `=` sign that case.

Comment: You can't use `*` in a look behind assertion